# как задать Location для FXMLLoader'a? IllegalStateException. JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Добрый день!
Так как проект складывается более, чем из 3-х файлов поместил fxml файлы в отдельную папку. При запуске FXML Loadera использовал следующий код:

```
FXMLLoader mainLoader = new FXMLLoader();
mainLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../fxml/sample.fxml"));
```

вместо кода, который Idea создает автоматически, т.к. в teampleat'е fxml файл находиться в одном пакете с FXMLLoader'ом.`FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));`

в Intellij Idea работает корректно, при создании jar-архива и запуске приложения выдает ошибку:

```
IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
```

Как преодолеть эту ошибку? Или Как правильно задать URL fxml файла, находящегося в другом пекедже?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный код будет:

```
FXMLLoader mainLoader = new FXMLLoader();
mainLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/javaFX/myprograms/phoneBook/fxml/edit.fxml"))
```

Где `"/com/javaFX/myprograms/phoneBook/fxml/edit.fxml"` - точная вложенность всех пакетов в проекте. 
Java не может корректно распознать путь, начинающийся на `../` который правильно распознает Idea.

Кому интересны детали: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755630/javafx-location-is-not-set-error